# JQuery AJAX fadeIn content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making my ajax updated div fade in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183638/making-my-ajax-updated-div-fade-in)

I want the content from AJAX call to `fadeIn` on my page, but when I use this code `$('#sub_container').html(content).fadeIn();` it doesn't work, even if I set the animation speed to super slow (`slow(5000)`)

```
$('.create').click(function(){
    loadingimg();
    document.title = 'Create Message';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'create.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(content){
            $('#sub_container').html(content);
            // $('#sub_container').html(content).fadeIn(); <- Fails
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183638/making-my-ajax-updated-div-fade-in, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262573/ajax-jquery-fade-in-of-php-content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.fadeIn()` function essentially makes the element visible, so will appear to do nothing if the element is *already* visible. You can ensure that's not the case by hiding the element:

```
$('#sub_container').hide().html(content).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, just tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure it's hidden to begin with, for example:

```
$('.create').click(function(){
$('#sub_container').fadeOut();    // fade out the current content
loadingimg();
document.title = 'Create Message';
$.ajax({
    url: 'create.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(content){
        $('#sub_container').html(content).stop().fadeIn();    // fade in the new content
    }
});
});
```

But that can get you jumping content as the element disappears so you have to account for that if necessary.